# CASE in WHEREclause

Tags: sql, oracle

```
WHERE
--from TABLE.PARAMETER1
    (b.is_ot_paycode = 'Y' OR 
-- from variableA
    b.is_ot_paycode = 'Y')
    AND
-- from TABLE.PARAMETER1
    (b.is_wh_paycode = 'Y'  OR 
-- from variableA
    b.is_wh_paycode = 'Y') 
-- from variableB
    AND b.is_ot_paycode = 'Y'
```

How can I create a `CASE` statement in my `WHERE` clause that when

```
b.is_wh_paycode = 'Y' (from variableA) and 
b.is_ot_paycode = 'Y'(from variableB) 
b.is_wh_paycode (from TABLE.PARAMETER1) would always be equal to 'N'?
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `case` for that.

```
WHERE (b.is_wh_paycode <> 'Y' or b.is_ot_paycode <> 'Y' or b.is_wh_paycode = 'N')
```

You can write it as a `case`:

```
WHERE b.is_wh_paycode = (case when b.is_wh_paycode = 'Y' and b.is_ot_paycode = 'Y' 
                              then 'N' else b.is_wh_paycode
                         end)
```

But it is not necessarily clearer.

NOTE:  both these assume that the columns do not take on `NULL` values.  If they do, then the SQL would need to take this into account.